# LIKE AND LIKE statement in yii2

Tags: jquery, mysql, yii2, sql-like

This is the query that I want:

```
SELECT * FROM `elenchi` WHERE ConvMon LIKE '%bol%' AND ConvMon LIKE '%maria%'
```

Can anyone help me to transform this query using the syntax Yii2?

I have built this query for the moment but is wrong:

```
if($this->ConvMon) {
        
        $query->andWhere(['like',"ConvMon",$this->ConvMon]); //this is the problem
                        
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean with " this query for the moment but is wrong" .?,  you have an error? show the error message.  Wrong result ? explain  better you goal .. anyway  update your question and add  also the other part of code for you active query  code  .. .

Comment: Seems like the "%" wildcards are missing.

Comment: Are you looking for a row ith _both_ 'maria' and 'bol' in it?   Or _either_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
provide 3rd element as array to achive this query

```
$query->andWhere(['like', 'ConvMon', ['bol', 'maria']]);
```

this line produce

```
WHERE ConvMon LIKE '%bol%' AND ConvMon LIKE '%maria%'
```